# How to Sort Data in Excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to Copy data from all Sheets to one sheet and Sort it Alphabetically.

My excel file contains CD names and Tracks, when i am sorting this data i m able to sort by CD Names but only first track of CD comes. rest of tracks are ignored.

please help me out for this.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: please show us your code and the sheet structure so that we could help you deeper

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the [`sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213557%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method of vba?

Besides, you can record a macro to create some code and adapt it to build a fully functional procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Does your data look like this?

```
A    B
CD1  Track1
     Track2
     Track3
CD2  Track1
     Track2
     Track3
```

If so, you need to fill in the blanks in column A.  Select A2:A??? (as far down as your track data goes).  Press F5 (Edit Goto), click Special Cells, Blanks.  This will select all the blank cells in column A for your data.

Next, in A2, type =A1 and enter using Control+Enter.  This will enter that formula in all the blank cells.  Control+Enter enters an array formula.  It's a way to enter a single formula in a bunch of cells at once. Your data should now look like

```
A    B
CD1  Track1
CD1  Track2
CD1  Track3
CD2  Track1
CD2  Track2
CD2  Track3
```

Now select A1:A???.  Edit - Copy.  Edit- Paste Special - Values (don't change the selection - paste right over the existing data).  Now if you sort on column A, all your CD1 tracks will be together.